# iPhone battery's capacity to hold electrical charge

Tags: iphone, battery

The AppleCare extended warranty covers the iPhone battery "when its capacity to hold an electrical charge has depleted fifty percent (50%) or more from its original specification."  But how do I measure that capacity?

On Macs, I can use the application [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) for this.  Is there something similar for the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst there are battery meters around, there's not really a way of measuring capacity without a full charge and discharge cycle. I think they mean that, compared to how long it lasted when new, it now lasts half as long after a full charge, with the same amount of usage. For example, if you always got 2 days of average use out of it before it complained about being down to 20%, and now you only get 1 day, then you can claim on the warranty. No idea how you prove the capacity has decreased to Apple though.

Comment: You're right.  I found the specifics in the Terms and Conditions: " ... the capacity of the covered iPhone 
battery to hold an electrical charge has depleted fifty (50%) percent or more from its original 
specification, (after being fully charged and the covered iPhone playing audio or video with 
all settings reset)".

Comment: I have no idea how I'd tell myself, let alone prove it to Apple.